# How do I find Docker image by its long name

Tags: docker

I very simple beginner question. I have the following line in my Dockerfile and I want to see what other versions (tags?) are available for it.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
```

I can't seem to find it on Docker Hub by entering lumps of that name/address string above.

The URL mcr.microsoft.com redirects to a page which says *"The discovery experience for MCR is provided through dockerhub."*

When I hit the link it goes to a Docker page but the UX is not the same as the Docker Hub search, and when I do search for `aspnet` I get a lots of results because it's not filtered just on Microsoft Container Registry.

It's confusing. When I tick the Verified Publisher filter and I only see one image from Bitnami.

Whatever (obvious) attempts I make to search for this image, I fail. Please show me how I can locate the Docker Hub page for an image from its name/address/id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo)

```
skopeo list-tags  docker://mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
```

Comment: Ah cool, thank you. And you're implying that this isn't a simple Docker Hub feature? (and I am, in fact, sane)

Comment: I think you can pull MCR images from DockerHub but not inspect or see the related tags, Skopeo inspects the mcr.microsoft.com remote repository directly